# How to Scroll To Element

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have this expression in JQuery

```js
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('.price-block').offset().top
}, 800);
```

So, i need the same but in native JS

Comment: Good news, jQuery code **is** JavaScript. You probably mean that you want to avoid jQuery and instead use native browser APIs (which are not part of JavaScript). In this case, that''s asking a lot.

Comment: @Pointy, yes, i want to rewrite site on JQuery in native JS

Comment: It's not "native JS". The browser APIs are part of the *browser*, not the JavaScript language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [HTMLElement.offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) in combination with [Window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

```js
const scrollToPriceBlock = () => {
  const EL_priceBlock = document.querySelector(".price-block");
  window.scrollTo({
    top: EL_priceBlock.offsetTop,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
};

scrollToPriceBlock();
```

```html
<p style="height: 200vh;">Scroll...</p>
<div class="price-block">PRICE BLOCK</div>
<p style="height: 200vh;">Scroll...</p>
```

Comment: Checked this, works. Thank you